# Excel-VBA: What's the meaning of "&" in Range function

Tags: vba, excel

What's the meaning and usage of "&" in the following piece of code?

```
Set Rng = Range("a1", Range("h" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&` is the string concatenation operator in VBA. So if `Rows.Count` = 10 then `"h" & Rows.Count` would produce a string that contains "h10".